# Por que em programas com soquetes, um servidor TCP possui sempre mais do que um soquete?

Tags: tcp

Pessoal alguém poderia me tirar essa dúvida?

Comment: De onde tirou essa premissa? Como você está "contando" o número de soquetes? Uma coisa é normalmente você ter um listener/dispatcher pra atender vários clientes, mas isso não necessariamente implica que toda aplicação precise disso como regra. Me parece que a pergunta parte de uma afirmação incorreta.